# How do I kill elasticsearch from the command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts

We are trying to run a script to stop elasticsearch.

When I execute `ps aux |grep elastic` I am getting:

```
root@baldelas01:/tmp# ps aux |grep elastic
root     3016819  0.0  0.1   8248  4164 pts/2    S    14:43   0:00 su elasticsearch
elastic+ 3016820  0.0  0.1   7460  4260 pts/2    S+   14:43   0:00 bash
elastic+ 3016870  0.8 33.9 5562772 1369948 pts/2 Sl   14:43   0:37 /bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-3054796781310172182 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=data -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32 -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m -Des.path.home=/opt/elasticsearch-6.6.1 -Des.path.conf=/opt/elasticsearch-6.6.1/config -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp /opt/elasticsearch-6.6.1/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -d
elastic+ 3016887  0.0  0.1 121920  6900 pts/2    Sl   14:43   0:00 /opt/elasticsearch-6.6.1/modules/x-pack-ml/platform/linux-x86_64/bin/controller
root     3019325  0.0  0.0   6432   736 pts/1    R+   15:54   0:00 grep --color=auto elastic
root@baldelas01:/tmp#
```

How do I get the PID : 3016870   in the script and execute kill -9?

I tried `pidof` but that does not give any result.

Comment: same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176341/find-process-id-by-command-used-by-the-process-and-kill-it replace ffmpeg by elasticsearch  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/80211/process-id-using-ps-aux  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/490961/getting-pid-of-program-via-terminal  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/7203/whats-the-terminal-command-for-finding-out-a-processs-id

Comment: Why not `sudo service elasticsearch stop` ? See also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/stopping-elasticsearch.html  They have a specific section on how to stop elasticsearch and why you should use specific commands. Killing should be the last resort ;) They also include a version using a pid :)

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, I tried the steps in the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/stopping-elasticsearch.html when i execute jps | grep Elasticsearch i get a result : 3016870 Elasticsearch. We have elastic search in /opt/elasticsearch-6.6.1 , I then navigated to that location and executed ./bin/elasticsearch -p /tmp/elasticsearch-pid -d however i dont see any file created /tmp by name elasticsearch-pid instead i see the file as elasticsearch-7267875706287918534 and inside that jna-3506402 . Hence, cat /tmp/elasticsearch-pid && echo does not result any PID. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

the `pidof` doesn't give any result because elastcisearch is run through `java` binary.

the not-so-simple solution to get the id would be:

```
ps -aux | grep 'elastic' | grep 'java' | awk -F " " '{ print $2 }'
```

which is:

- print all processes ( `ps -aux` )
- filter the result by 'elastic' keyword ( `grep 'elastic'` )
- filter the result by 'java' keyword ( `grep 'java'` )
- only print second column (  `awk -F " " '{ print $2 }'` )

then you can kill specific ID using `kill -9` if you really need to.
However, please note it's always better to securely shut down the service by using the command suggested by **Rinzwind** in one of the comments.

Comment: Thanks Jan, When i executed ps -aux | grep 'elastic' | grep 'java' | awk -F " " '{ print $2 }' i dont get any result. root@baldelas01:/opt# ps -aux | grep 'elastic' | grep 'java' | awk -F " " '{ print $2 }'
root@baldelas01:/opt# . So i tried removing "-" and used ps aux | grep 'elastic' | grep 'java' | awk -F " " '{ print $2 }' got the result. Thanks let me try this in script and see if it works.

Comment: In the Script i tried stop)
    echo "Stopping $APP"
    processID="ps -ef | grep 'elastic' | grep 'java' | awk -F " " '{ print $2 }'"
    echo $processID
    sleep 30
    kill $processID
    #/bin/su -m $USER -c "kill -9 (ps -ef | grep elastic)  &> /dev/null"
    sleep 30
    echo "$APP stopped successfully" However when i execute the restart file i get Stopping ElasticSearch
./elastic-auto-restart: 22:  '{ print  }': not found
    ;;

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question because: pasting script in a comment makes in barely readable. you're telling us there's issue with line 22, but you're not pasting the full script. I can only see ~7 lines of it. then again I think you're still trying to kill something manually which already has a stop script in /etc/init.d/elasticsearch (hint: yes, it also contains a location of elasticsearch PID file, which contains process ID)

Comment: Thanks i have created a seperate question as per the request with full script. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334513/related-to-how-do-i-kill-elasticsearch-from-the-command-line

Comment: Hi All, Please help