# Related to How do I kill elasticsearch from the command line?

Tags: 20.04

I noticed that the java and elastic search had same pid so we wrote a script to kill the java instead.

Attaching the script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#elasticsearch startup script
#chkconfig: 2345 80 05
#description: ElasticSearch


APP=ElasticSearch
# Name of the user to run as
USER=elasticsearch

# Location of Java JDK
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241

case "$1" in

 # Stop command
  stop)
    echo "Stopping $APP"
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "pkill -9 -f java;"
    #sleep 30
    echo "$APP stopped successfully"
    ;;

  # Start command
  start)
    echo "Starting $APP"
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "/opt/elasticsearch-6.6.1/bin/elasticsearch -d &> /dev/null"
    echo "$APP started successfully"
    ;;
  # Stop command
 # stop)
  #  echo "Stopping $APP"
   # /bin/su -m $USER -c "$BASE/bin/shutdown.sh &> /dev/null"
    #echo "$APP stopped successfully"
    #;;
   #Restart command
   restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 60
        $0 start
        ;;
  *)
 echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$APP restart}"
  exit 1
   ;;
esac

exit 0
```

However when I execute this script I see

```
root@test:/var/atlassian# ./elastic-auto-restart restart
Stopping ElasticSearch
pkill: killing pid 1956409 failed: Operation not permitted
ElasticSearch stopped successfully
Starting ElasticSearch
ElasticSearch started successfully
```

The script is working and the restarting of the service is successful. But i notice this error "pkill: killing pid 1956409 failed: Operation not permitted"
User Elasticsearch has a sudo access in this machine.

Regards
Aravind Viswanathan.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is this particular line in the `stop` part:

```
    /bin/su -m $USER -c "pkill -9 -f java;"
```

because the user is:

```
USER=elasticsearch
```

and elasticsearch doesn't have permission to use pkill (only root has).

To fix this you can remove usage of elasticsearch for it (since you're running the command as root anyway) so it looks like this:

```
pkill -9 -f java;
```

this should work because you are already `root` user when running this command and don't need to run this command as another user (no /bin/su needed)

Comment: Great Jan, Thanks a lot that solved my issue.

Comment: @AravindViswanathan if possible, please mark the question as solved. (mark the answer as accepted answer)

Comment: Where is the option to select "Accepted answer" ?

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer